# Ansible error - No module named packaging.version

Tags: python, azure, ansible

I have Centos 7.3 with ansible version 2.3.

```
Ansible 2.3.0.0
config file = ../ansible.cfg
configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
python version = 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
```

I need to run ansible playbooks in Azure VM's.

I get the following error when I run

```
fatal: [52.170.201.24]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 52.170.201.24 closed.\r\n", 
"module_stdout": "\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k2CnFR/ansible_module_azure_rm_virtualmachine.py\", line 445, in <module>\r\n    
from ansible.module_utils.azure_rm_common import *\r\n  
File \"/tmp/ansible_k2CnFR/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 29, in <module>\r\nImportError: No module named packaging.version\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
```

Tried installing setuptools as indicated in several sites

```
sudo pip install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.6.0 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from setuptools)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from setuptools)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from setuptools)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools
```

Tried upgrading pip as mentioned in several sites and got it to the latest version

```
pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

which pip
/usr/bin/pip
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

UPDATE:

52.170.201.24 is the IP Address of the Azure Virtual machine which is part of the inventory hosts.

I'm actually trying to power on an Azure Virtual machine with this ansible code in my ansible control machine

```
- name: Power On Docker repo if Azure
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: HpsaPoc
    name: DockerRepo
    started: yes
  when:  "{{cloud_provider}}" == 'azure'
```

I can't wrap my head around this python/pip configurations, I had tried installing python 3.5 and pip3 but didn't help, so deleted it as I didn't know how to uninstall it. Please help.

Comment: What is `52.170.201.24` and where did you run `pip`?

Comment: Updated with details. So, it seems like this code tries to run on the target VM which is in Azure and it complains because python/pip is not installed on it? Then how does one power on a VM or perform any action on an Azure VM by running playbooks on the ansible control machine?

Comment: You are trying to run Ansible action on a stopped machine???

Comment: I need to power on Azure virtual machine using ansible playbook. I took it from this site http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/azure_rm_virtualmachine_module.html#examples..... Just to clear some confusion, 52.170.201.24 is a Azure virtual machine which is already powered on and I'm successful in configuring it. Dockerrepo is another Azure VM which I need to power on separately as part of my ansible playbook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you try to execute `azure_rm_virtualmachine` from remote host, not from your Ansible control host.

Try:

```
- name: Power On Docker repo if Azure
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    resource_group: HpsaPoc
    name: DockerRepo
    started: yes
  when: cloud_provider == 'azure'
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error. After several errors and debugging, I'm stuck with this error now which doesn't make much sense,  fatal: [x.x.x.x -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Error retrieving resource group HpsaPoc - __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"}

Comment: You may have incompatible versions of `ansible` and `azure` packages.

Comment: it is considering when:  "{{cloud_provider}}" == 'azure' to be an argument and worked when it was removed.

Comment: I was blind to see jinja braces there, I've updated the answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The above error is occurred due to your environment doesn't have *packaging module*.

To solve this issue by installing *packaging module*.

**pip install packaging**

The above command will install packaging module of *16.8 version*

Comment: Thanks, this helped me on an upgrade to Ansible 2.5.0.